# Allow '@' inside string regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm parsing some HTML and using a regular expression, currently I have:

```
(?<='>)(.*?\w)(?=<)
```

The source is a little messy:

```
 <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2;height:17.15pt'>
  <td width=319 valign=top style='width:239.4pt;background:#C0504D;padding:
  0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:17.15pt'>
  <p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='color:white'>Personal Email Address<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
  </td>
  <td width=319 valign=top style='width:239.4pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
  height:17.15pt'>
  <p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><a
  href="mailto:djmarkjohnstone@hotmail.com">email@addr.com</a></span><span
  style='color:#0070C0'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
```

The result (from the fully parsed source code):

> 1: Name 1: John Smith 1: Personal Email Address 1: Start Date 1:
>   13/07/2014 1: End Date 1: 31/08/2014 1: Cost Centre 1: Building 1:
>   Date of Birth 1: 15/04/1978

It refuses to capture the email address because of the '@'.

How would I capture the @ within my regex?

**UPDATE:**

```
(?<='>)(.*?\w)(?=<)
```

The issue seems to be with the apostrophe not the '@', 
how would I add OR `">`

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser if you're trying to parse HTML? E.g. the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) for .NET.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I would probably use this in future but in my workplace I'm a little restricted on what I can and cannot add to my machine. Nifty little pack though, I'll be using this at home ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem mainly with the quotes not with the `@` symbol,

```
(?<='>|">)(.*?\w)(?=<)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/5)

The above regex would looks after to the `'>` or `">` and does a shortest match where the last character must be a word character followed by `<` symbol.

Comment: I noticed this a few minutes ago, thanks Avinash, I didn't know how to do the OR. Much appreciated.